# How to insert a row to two tables sharing the same primary key at once?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming the following table structures:

```
table1:
id - LONG primary key
data1 - INT

table2:
id - LONG primary key (constraint references table1.id)
data1 - INT
data2 - INT
data3 - INT
```

Table 1 does not depend on table 2, but if there's an entry in table 2, it has to reference the row in table 1.

Currently, through my Java backend, to insert a new row to the tables, I `INSERT` to `table1`, get the generated keys, and then use the generated `id` from the row I just inserted as the primary key for the row I am inserting to `table2`. The process takes a while, especially when the table gets really big.

What can I do to insert rows to both tables in one query without having to wait for the result of the query which inserts to `table1`, while still making sure the row which gets added to `table2` has the same primary key as the row I am adding to `table`?

Comment: There's no way to insert into two tables at once in SQL. The time to insert into a table shouldn't depend on the size of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't insert into two tables at once. Use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function to get the ID that was generated for table 1 when inserting into table 2

```
INSERT INTO table1 (data1) VALUES (123);
INSERT INTO table2 (id, data1, data2, data2) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 111, 222, 333);
```

If you were using an API function to get the generated ID, this avoids that extra query.